# In django, how can I hold a class in memory for use in views without having to construct them every time?

Tags: python, django

For example, if I have a relatively large csv that I will use to lookup values based on the json parameters provided by an HTTP request.

Ideally, I wouldn't have to load that large csv every time the endpoint is called and instead, use a lazily loaded variable:

```
class CSVService:
    
     #static getter
     def get_csv_service()
          if not csv_service:
               csv_service = CSVService()
          return csv_service

     #Other functions...

def my_view(request):
     service = CSVService.get_csv_service()
     service.some_function()
     ...
```

Any Ideas where I would create such a class that the data could be reused between requests?

Comment: Don't quite understand the question. You want the initiate the list once and then use it in your API without having to initiate the list again?

Comment: That is essentially the question, although not necessarily a list. Would be more convenient if it was a general object instead of a list. But yes, Create the object once and use it multiple times while the server is running. 

Thank you for your reply! :)

Comment: Why not store the content of the CSV in an DB and work with the ORM from there?